# Rearranging the rows in the numpy and keeping track of each row

Tags: python-3.x, conv-neural-network, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2000 numpy arrays of size 7 x 11. The rows are arranged in the following order of variables: pi, Tajima's D, Theta, dust kurtosis, J1/J2, J1, J2. That is first row always corresponds to pi, second row corresponds to Tajima's D and so on.

What I want to do is shuffle the rows but also keeping track of in which row has that variable moved to. For example, Tajima's D, Theta, pi, distkurtosis, J1/J2, J1, J2. And I want to keep track that now pi is in row 3. How can I achieve that? Please note, I want to only move the rows and not the columns.

Also, is there a way to make all possible combinations while keeping track of where each variable has move to?

My apologies if it is a really basic question. But, I'm having a hard time finding a solution for this problem.

My code thus far:

```
def interchange(array, n, m): 
   rows = n 
   #print(array)
   #print('\n')

   # swapping of element
   for i in range(m): 
       t = array[0][i] 

       array[0][i] = array[5][i] 
       array[5][i] = t 

       t = array[4][i]
       array[0][i] = array[8][i]
       array[8][i] = t

   #print(array)
   return array

###Calling the function 
for i in range(2000):
    h1[i] = interchange(h1[i], n, m)
```

Answer (score 0):

> keeping track of in which row has that variable moved to

Tack on an `original_index` column, and give it eleven sequential values according to the original row numbers.

> shuffle the rows

Tack on an `index` column, fill it with random numbers, and sort on that.
Choose new random numbers and re-sort if you want to re-shuffle.

Better, choose `seed = 0`, and fill the `index` column with [sha224](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html)(seed, row), so instead of random you have a deterministic function of the row.
Increment the `seed` if you want to re-shuffle.

> is there a way to make all possible combinations

Yes, use the [`permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) library function to populate the `index` column.
Re-sort on `index` for each successive permutation.

Comment: Is it possible to give an example. I've made some code. But I have to manually put in the indices. I've edited my code above so you can see my code. I want to reshuffle the rows and then see if my network will still be able to categorise these matrices in the right way.